# How to filter files from Node.js Debugger

Tags: node.js, node-debugger

When using the [Node.js Debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) with Chrome DevTools it's desirable to only debug the code you have written, and skip over code in `node_modules`. This can be done by [blackboxing](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code#blackbox_third-party_code) `node_modules`. However [Node.js's own javascript code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js) is not clearly under a file path that can be blackboxed (as seen in the picture below). How does one filter all of Node.js's internal javascript code from being stepped through in the Chrome DevTools debugger?

[image: Node.js internal javascript code]